# xslt: assigning variables equal to one of two cases

Tags: xslt, conditional-statements

I want to use the attribute `@sourcename` in the following way, as a convenience:

If `@sourcename` has a dot in it, the part before the first dot should be assigned to `$srcgroup` and the part after the first dot should be assigned to `$srcword`.

Otherwise `$srcgroup` should be set equal to `@sourcename` and `$srcword` should be the empty string.

In both cases I want to do the same things using `$srcgroup` and `$srcword`.

I tried this with the following fragment:

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="contains(@sourcename, '.')">     
     <xsl:variable name="srcgroup" select="substring-before(@sourcename, '.')"/> 
     <xsl:variable name="srcword" select="substring-after(@sourcename, '.')" />
   </xsl:when> 
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:variable name="srcgroup" select="@sourcename" />
     <xsl:variable name="srcword" />                     
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

<foo group="{$srcgroup}" word="{$srcword}" />
<!-- there's some other more complicated users of $srcgroup and $srcword -->
```

The problem is I get an error (this is using JAXP in Java):

```
ERROR:  [my xsl file]: line 35: Variable or parameter 'srcgroup' is undefined.'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:825)
```

If I understand this right, I'm guessing the variables only have the scope of the particular case in the `<xsl:choose>` block. Is there any way to get around this? I don't want to have to repeat my other code twice.

---

p.s. I found a workaround:

```
<xsl:variable name="srcgroup" select="substring-before(concat(@sourcename, '.'), '.')" /> 
<xsl:variable name="srcword" select="substring-after(@sourcename, '.')" />
```

but I still want to know how to solve my original question, for future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Just use** (no conditionals necessary):

```
  <xsl:variable name="srcgroup" select=
  "substring-before(concat(@sourcename, '.'), '.')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="srcword" select=
  "substring-after(@sourcename, '.')"/>
```

**Complete example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="x|y">
  <xsl:variable name="srcgroup" select=
  "substring-before(concat(@sourcename, '.'), '.')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="srcword" select=
  "substring-after(@sourcename, '.')"/>

  $srcgroup = "<xsl:value-of select="$srcgroup"/>"
  $srcword = "<xsl:value-of select="$srcword"/>"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>
  <x sourcename="a.b.c"/>
  <y sourcename="noDots"/>
</t>
```

**the wanted result is produced in both cases**:

```
  $srcgroup = "a"
  $srcword = "b.c"

  $srcgroup = "noDots"
  $srcword = ""
```

**Explanation**: Unnecessary logic avoided by placing a *sentinel*.

---

**Compare this to the much more verbose conditional syntax**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="x|y">
  <xsl:variable name="srcgroup">
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="contains(@sourcename, '.')">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@sourcename, '.')"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="@sourcename"/>
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="srcword">
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="contains(@sourcename, '.')">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@sourcename, '.')"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise/>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  $srcgroup = "<xsl:value-of select="$srcgroup"/>"
  $srcword = "<xsl:value-of select="$srcword"/>"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this more verbose transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), again the same correct result is produced**:

```
  $srcgroup = "a"
  $srcword = "b.c"

  $srcgroup = "noDots"
  $srcword = ""
```

Comment: If you read my comment at the end of my post, you'll see that I figured that out... this is helpful to handling that specific case, but it doesn't answer my question about how to conditionally assign a variable.

Comment: By the way, you have an error -- you shouldn't be using the concat in the `substring-after` case, as it produces an extra dot at the end of `srcword` in the non-empty case.

Comment: @JasonS: I have fixed my answer. And yes, it exactly answers thequestion how to conditionally define a variable. As you can see, no conditionals are necessary for defining the variables in the wanted way.

Comment: @JasonS: So, have you tried this and do you still have any problems? :)

Comment: I tried it, and edited my question accordingly, before you even posted your answer. My question isn't how to reach a solution which avoids conditionally defining a variable, since I know how to do that. My question is how to conditionally define a variable.

Comment: @JasonS: You must have emphasized in your question that you just needed to know the syntax. Please, have a look at my updated answer -- at the end I provide the requested solution showing the complete conditional syntax. Of course, wherever possible, the abbreviated solution is recommended.

Answer (score 5):

It's more like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="srcgroup">
 <xsl:choose...>
  ...
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: +1, but could you help me with the syntax? I'm not familiar with how to use `<xsl:variable>` without a `select=`

Comment: The content of the tag is the value of the variable. Put `<xsl:value-of .../>` where you woult put assignment in the `<xsl:when>`.

Comment: And look here — http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt — whenever in doubt, really helpful resource.

Comment: Huh -- usually when I look at w3.org I find the normative standards really cryptic. But it looks like they've tried a little harder than normal to be clear about XSLT.

Comment: Yes, the xslt is very clear and is really convenient referene.